# Links don't work on new server

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I've recently moved from server with php4 to php5. Now I cant open content in my page. Links look like this "page.com/news-it-is-rainy-day-1.html". But when I try to open link I just get the archive (news.html) which should be only seen if there are no news in the database. I also use smarty template engine.

My rewrite rule in .htacces looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^news-(.*)\.html$ news.php?do=read&id=$1
RewriteRule ^news.html$ news.php

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

Comment: Have you examined the server logs or http headers to see what is actually happening when you click a link?

Comment: Could this be because PHP safe mode is on?

Answer (score 1):

Is mod_rewrite enabled in apache in the new server? If not, it will ignore your RewriteEngine on in the .htaccess file